# How to configure Intel ME and AMT?

Tags: boot, bios, supermicro, intel-amt

I have a computer whose [chipset specs](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/63984/intel-c602-chipset.html) say

> Intel vPro® Platform Eligibility: Yes

[Its CPU specs](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75790/intel-xeon-processor-e5-2630-v2-15m-cache-2-60-ghz.html) also say

> Intel vPro® Platform Eligibility: Yes

However, the BIOS setup (`Del`) just states the version of Intel ME. No apparent way to configure AMT, etc. This is the motherboard: [SuperMicro X9DRG-QF](https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/xeon/c600/x9drg-qf.cfm)

How do I configure Intel ME and AMT? (I tried `Ctrl-p` during the boot-up, but that didn't do anything. `Ctrl-s` brings up some irrelevant menus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the AMT features were deliberately turned off by the OEM, because server motherboards (which SuperMicro specializes in) typically include a *discrete* management controller (BMC) which provides KVM-over-LAN and various other remote access features.

Some of those features (e.g. remote power or serial console) are provided through the standard IPMI 2.0 protocol, which Intel AMT wouldn't support. (Others are accessible through a web interface or SSH or proprietary RPC.)

SuperMicro often call their management controller just "IPMI". In this case you have a "Renesas SH7757" BMC listed in the spec sheet, and it does the same job as AMT generally would, but with SuperMicro's software instead of Intel's.